# Определить число баннеров и виджетов по коду html-страницы

Tags: html, python, виджет

Как определить число баннеров и виджетов по коду html-страницы (желательно используя одну из библиотек питона)?

Под баннером понимаю – гиперссылку с изображением на сайт рекламодателя, под виджетом – небольшой блок, который содержит данные или сервис другого сайта, не хотелось бы конечно с регулярными выражениями возиться, надеялся, что какая-то библиотека для этих вещей есть. Если вдруг Вы представляете, как это можно описать регулярным выражением, то напишите пожалуйста.

**Обновление**

Есть куча html страниц, надо определить присутствуют в них банеры и виджеты или нет(и если есть в каком количестве), под ними понимается, то что указано выше. Сам не с html в основном работаю, это побочная задача к основной, поэтому формальнее не могу. На счет рекламодателей, буду признателен, если кто базу данных с такими посоветует.

Comment: Можно, наверное, использовать регулярные выражения. Но тут все зависит от того, что именно понимать под "_баннерами и виджетами_".

Comment: Если перечислить сайты рекламодателей, то можно ещё попробовать вычленить эту информацию с помощью разбора структуры html. В противном случае, нужно как-то уметь отличать рекламные ссылки от обычных.

Comment: В любом случае, для начала нужно четко формализовать задачу и исправить запрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать четкий однозначный ответ.

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии что в HTML будут все баннеры.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под словом все?

Comment: Короче, страница отображенная в браузере и ее html-код, который отдается с сервера - две большие разницы.

Comment: В данном случае интересен только html код.

Comment: Покажите, что вы уже пытались сделать для решения задачи? Какой-то код решения уже есть или вы хотите чтобы вам его предложили?

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже ответитили [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450161/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), такая функциональность есть в AdBlock, написанном на javascript. Можно использовать его или написать своё решение на основе фильтров, используемых этим расширением, например [EasyList](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)