# База данных рекламодателей(интернет баннеров)

Tags: реклама

Никто не знает хорошую базу данных, в которой перечислены списки url известных в настоящее время рекламодателей интернет баннеров.

Comment: Неясно, какого рода сведения вас интересуют.
Список организаций, занимающихся рекламой с расценками?
Список рекламных URL?

Comment: Исправил, список рекламных URL.

Comment: Далее, будет полезно назвать цель всего этого мероприятия.

Answer (score 1):

Куски Adbloсk'а. Выглядит например [так](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)

UPD. Судя по озвученной (на третьей итерации комментирования, ура-ура) задаче, вас может заинтересовать старинная тулза Proxomitron. Она эту статистику считает.

Comment: спасибо, целью является по html-коду страницы посчитать число баннеров

Comment: Так это adblock прекрасно умеет делать. И API у него какой-то есть.

Comment: Спасибо, пороюсь в API тогда, эти данные мне нужны для сбора информации с кучи файлов в raw-html, а Proxomitron вроде бы никакого API не предоставляет для такой обработки.

Comment: Если вы какими-то чудесами телепатии поняли вопрос, то отредактируйте его, пожалуйста. Сейчас он выглядит как опросник и наверняка будет закрыт, если таким и останется.